# mysql console > mysqlbinlog You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I have WAMP installed that has been binary logging all changes in my database. I found the logs, the mysql console also shows them when I perform a SHOW BINARY LOGS. But when I try to read them by executing:

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000197
```

it gives me that error:

```
ERROR 1016(42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that   corresponds     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000197' at line 1
```

MySQL version is 5.5.20

Comment: I believe `mysqlbinlog` is a shell command, not a mysql command.

Comment: Facing similar issue , are we have any solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you used shell command ?

```
  shell> mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000197
```